# Access Jenkins https via nginx Bitnami

Tags: nginx, jenkins, bitnami

Im configuring Jenkins on gke.

jenkins is on namespace devops-tools.
Nginx is on namespace kube-system.

I want to configure access to Jenkins for https with private domain.

```
- Helm: version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.13.0", GitCommit:"825e86f6a7a38cef1112bfa606e4127a706749b1", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.20.8"}
```

```
- Kubernetes: Client Version: v1.28.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.27.3-gke.100
```

Chart version

```
jenkins-4.8.2
```

I configured the Jenkins from helm chart jenkinsci/helm-charts with some of the values like this:

```
httpsKeyStore:
      jenkinsHttpsJksSecretName: ''
      jenkinsHttpsJksSecretKey: "jenkins-jks-file"
      jenkinsHttpsJksPasswordSecretName: ""
      jenkinsHttpsJksPasswordSecretKey: "https-jks-password"
      enable: true
      httpPort: 8081
      path: "/var/lib/jenkins"
      fileName: "keystore.jks"
      password: "some password"
      jenkinsKeyStoreBase64Encoded: | 
         /u3+7QAAAAIAAAA...

  ingress:
    enabled: true
    apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1"
    ingressClassName: nginx
    hostName: "jenkins.devops-tools-k8s-cluster.internal.com"
    tls:
    - secretName: jenkins-tls-secret
      hosts:
        - jenkins.devops-tools-k8s-cluster.internal.com
```

This was actually working with port forward. I can see my cert is there.

I configured this secret for the Nginx:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: jenkins-tls-secret
  namespace: devops-tools
data:
  tls.crt: base64 crt
  tls.key: base64 key
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

on the nginx logs i got this:

```
I1108 09:05:56.567114       1 store.go:585] "Secret was added and it is used in ingress annotations. Parsing" secret="devops-tools/jenkins-tls-secret"
I1108 09:05:56.568214       1 backend_ssl.go:67] "Adding secret to local store" name="devops-tools/jenkins-tls-secret"
```

But when im trying to access my url https://jenkins.devops-tools-k8s-cluster.internal.com
im getting the error:

```
2023/11/08 09:42:57 [error] 32#32: *128412 [lua] certificate.lua:263: call(): failed to set DER private key: d2i_PrivateKey_bio() failed, context: ssl_certificate_by_lua*, client: 172.38.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

As for nginx im using https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/nginx with latest stable version.

I tried other version to make sure there is the same issue with them.

the cert is self-sighed as its private domain in gcp.

what did i do wrong? is there a problem with nginx of bitnami?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was a problem with bitnami version.
I changed it to a newer one and its working fine now.